# Performance impact of virtual methods

Tags: c#, performance, oop, unit-testing

To accommodate unit testing and mocking it's become a common practice to declare methods and properties as virtual. Is there a performance impact of declaring something virtual as supposed to non-virtual?

Comment: You think _design for testability_ is just making everything `virtual` and all classes `open`? Hmm...

Comment: @StefanHanke: I don't see anything suggesting that the OP thinks it's *just* that.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it should be done when it's not needed... It's just one measure that can improve testability when appropriate

Comment: @JonSkeet I was refering to the term _common practice_, but you're right, my statement is too general. 
@TGH We had a discussion whether _any_ adaption of production code to a specific test framework is meaningful. For example, switching from `rhino mocks` to `moq` (which uses a different, more "powerful" technique) means you can intercept any call at all, even static function calls. We concluded not doing it at all and instead try to design differently to facilitate testing.

Comment: I am actually very surprised that Moles doesn't seem to be more popular. It seems to have so many advantages over MOQ etc. You can basically mock anything in Moles (even private methods) It seems like MOQ is still relying on interfaces and virtuals..

Comment: Oops, sorry, `moq` uses dynamic proxies, too (don't use it). I meant those that intercept via the profiler interface.

Comment: @TGH Moles would be popular but it's not readily supported at the moment, it seems. Go to their site, it just recently got "turned off"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, the difference is that virtual methods are called using a Callvirt Opcode, whereas not virtual methods use a standard Call Opcode. Call Opcodes are definitely faster than Callvirt, but I've never ever every found it nearly substantial enough to justify making design decisions based on this.

`Premature optimization is the root of all evil.`

Comment: IIRC, the C# compiler will use CallVirt for all instance methods, regardless of whether they're virtual. That way the CLR does the nullity check.

Comment: @JohnSkeet So does that mean that at the end of the day there is really no difference?

Comment: Good point John - you're right with the exception of value type instance methods I think - for which the compiler emits an Opcodes.Call.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not really.

It is not something you are going to notice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics, but I do know that you don't have to worry about it for 99% of apps out there.

btw - If choose to Mock interfaces instead of classes you won't need virtual methods.

Good luck,
Tom

Comment: You have the same indirection 'penalty' with an interface as a virtual method.